# Spectrum of an operator besides its eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to figure out the following operator problem:

Assume $X$ is a Banach space and $P∈B(X)$ is a projection with $ran (P)≠[0]$.

I have already shown that $0$ and $1$ are eigenvalues of $P$, since this was asked at the start of this exercise. Now in the next question, they ask me to show that the spectrum of P is equal to {$0$,$1$}:

i.e: "*show  that* $σ(P)=$ {$0$ ,$1$}".

Now I'm quite confused, since I've just calculated that is eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$ and am not sure what to show next. How do I show the spectrum of P is indeed defined as given above?  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have to show that $P-\lambda I$ is invertible for every $\lambda\neq 0,1$.

Comment: @Ruy Could you help me a bit to how thats done? How do I show $P−λI$ is invertible? Do I need to factor out the lambda?

Comment: Try finding an inverse of the form $P-\mu I$.

Comment: @Ruy so I'm looking for a solution of $μ$ for $(P−λI)*(P−μI) = I$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said: try finding an inverse of the form $aP+bI$.  Thus you should look for a solution of $a$ and $b$ for $(P-\lambda I)*(aP+bI)$.